# ASP.Net web stress test tool for actual use

Tags: asp.net, load, webserver

WCAT, httperf, openload - good tools to simulate static load on the server.

I need to test actual load of an ASP.Net solution. Meaning if I'm testing 1k simultaneous users, the tool needs to log on 1k different usernames (one for each simultaneous connection) and enter 1k different strings into a textbox. On top of that the cookie and FORM-data (i.e. ViewState) for each connection will be unique and should be preserved.

What tools are there to do this? Free=Good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Grinder might be worth a try - I'm not sure it can do everything you want, but it is free :)

http://grinder.sourceforge.net/

Comment: As the only answer you win by default. :) Had some trouble setting it up, but I'll get it working when I have time to look closer at it.